Reduce raster file size during QGIS Python script processing
I wrote a Python script based for QGIS that is using the raster calculator to create a new raster based on two existing raster inputs. My problem is, that each output file is 35 GiB and I do have not enough space for multiple of these files (as I need around 150 of them).
Is there a way to reduce the file size during the Python script before the file is saved (e.g. through compression)?
Here is the script I'm currently using:
import processing
import os

# Iterate from 0 to 15
for i in [float(x) for x in range(0, 5)]:

    var2 = 'dem@1 <= (' + str(i) + '} + 2.5)'
    slr_in_cm = str(int(i * 100))

    dem = QgsRasterLayer('/Users/niklas/Documents/_Thesis/Analysis/OutputData/DK-DEM_terrain_merged.tif')
    output = '/Users/niklas/Documents/_Thesis/Analysis/OutputData/floodings/Raster_Calculation/' + slr_in_cm + '.tif'
    entries = []
    ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    ras.ref = 'dem@1'
    ras.raster = dem
    ras.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append(ras)
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator(var2, output, 'GTiff', dem.extent(), dem.width(), dem.height(), entries)

    # Run the calculator
    result = calc.processCalculation()
    if result == QgsRasterCalculator.Success:
        print("Step 1: Raster calculation {i} completed successfully")
        
        water = QgsRasterLayer('/Users/niklas/Documents/_Thesis/Analysis/OutputData/floodings/Raster_Calculation/' + slr_in_cm + '.tif')
        output_depth = '/Users/niklas/Documents/_Thesis/Analysis/OutputData/floodings/Raster_Calculation/' + slr_in_cm + '_depth.tif'
        
        depth_calc = '(dem@1 <= water@1) * (dem@1 - water@1)'
        
        entries = []
        
        dem_ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        dem_ras.ref = 'dem@1'
        dem_ras.raster = dem
        dem_ras.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(dem_ras)
        
        water_ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        water_ras.ref = 'water@1'
        water_ras.raster = water
        water_ras.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(water_ras)
        
        calc = QgsRasterCalculator(depth_calc, output_depth, 'GTiff', dem.extent(), dem.width(), dem.height(), entries)

        # Run the calculator
        result = calc.processCalculation()
        
        if result == QgsRasterCalculator.Success:
            print('Step 2: Calculate depth completed successfully.')
            os.remove('/Users/niklas/Documents/_Thesis/Analysis/OutputData/floodings/Raster_Calculation/' + slr_in_cm + '.tif')
            print('Step 3: File deleted')
    else:
        print("Failed to calculate raster {i}", calc.lastError())

